# Boost.Asio call user-defined function with callback

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, boost-asio

Using Boost.Asio how one can asynchronously call user-defined function with calling callback like Boost.Asio's standard async calls?

Something like:

```
boost::asio::async_write(..., WriteHandler);
```

But with user function:

```
async_call(UserFunction, ..., UserCompletionHandler);
```

which will call `UserFunction` and after it completes call `UserCompletionHandler`?

I can implement `async_call` using `deadline_timer`s, but is there a way to implement it without them?

Comment: You can use the [`boost::asio::io_service::post()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/post.html) method to enqueue an asynchronous call. Is that what you want?

Comment: @rhashimoto Yes, but I want to know when it will be finished. Simply calling callback in that posted call will block the queue...

Comment: Why not just post a lambda that calls `UserFunction` and then calls `UserCompletionHandler` (or write a convenience function that does that)?

Comment: @rhashimoto i'll try...